# Projection with Transformation using ogr2ogr GDAL

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, gdal

I am trying to reproject a shape from EPSG:3857 to EPSG:102008 (North America Equal Area Conic Albers) using GDAL.

I need to use the "NAD 83 to WGS 1984 5 (WKID 1515)" transformation since the datum are different.

My current command is using the -s_srs and -t_srs parameters. 
i.e. `-s_srs EPSG:3857 -t_srs EPSG:102008`

How do I inject this particular transformation into the above command?

Comment: There is no such projection (EPSG:102008)  that is EPSG (https://www.epsg-registry.org/) do not define a CRS with that number.  There is an ESRI code of that number.